# Give a TDI system $Ax\leq b$ describing $P$ with $A$ and $b$ integral.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, vector-spaces, convex-analysis

Let $P\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be the convex hull of the points $(0,0)$, $(3,1)$ and $(-1,2)$.

**Exercise:** Give a TDI system $Ax\leq b$ describing $P$ with $A$ and $b$ integral.

I know the following:

Many combinatorial min-max relations can be understood as a result of LP-duality $$\max \{w^Tx: Ax\leq b\}= \min\{ y^Tb:y^TA=w^T,y\geq 0\}$$ combined with integrality of optimal solutions on the primal and dual side.

**Def:** Let $Ax\leq b$ be a rational system of linear inequalities and let $P:=\{x:Ax\leq b\}$ be the associated polyhedron. The system $Ax\leq b$ is Totally Dual Integral (TDI) if for every integral objective vector $w$, the minimum in the dual is attained by an integral vector $y$ (if the minimum is finite).

*What I should do:* I need to find a TDI system $Ax\leq x$ such that $P = \{x:Ax\leq b\}$ is the convex hull of the points $(0,0),(3,1)$ and $(-1,2)$ and that $A$ and $b$ are integral. So I think I probably should identify $P$ first.

**My questions:**

- How do I solve this exercise?
- (Optional) How do I find $P$, where $P$ is the convex hull of the points $(0,0), (3,1)$ and $(-1,2)$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to find three lines:
one that intersects (0,0) and (3,1);
one that intersects (0,0) and (-1,2);
and the line that intersect (-1,2).

Then you should be able to find the matrix A and the corresponding vector b.

For the first line for example you have: $x_1=a x_2 +b$, where $a=\frac{1}{3}$ and $b=0$.

That is how you identify $P$.